# SQL RANK() Calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have an insert query I'm currently using in a stored procedure that works as it should. It is as follows:

```
insert into tblAgentRank (AgtID, RankType, Rank, TimeFrame, RankValue)
select AgtID, 8, RANK() OVER (order by SUM(ColPrem*ModeValue) DESC) as Rank, 'Y', SUM(ColPrem*ModeValue)
from tblAppsInfo
where CompanyID in (select CompanyID from tblCompanyInfo
    where DeptID = 7)
group by AgtID
order by Rank
```

This creates a total for each agent, and ranks them against their peers.

---

I need to create a similar statement that does the following calculations:

- If PolicyTypeID = 4, calculate SUM(ColPrem*ModeValue) * 0.07
- Else, calculate SUM((ColPrem*ModeValue) + (ExcessPrem * 0.07))
- Sum these two statements together for each agent, and then do the rank on the total.

I could easily do one of those, as demonstrated by the 1st query. My mental block is stemming from needing to do it on a case by case basis based on PolicyTypeID.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. SQL 2005.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this `select` statement does the calculation that you want:

```
select AgtID, 8,
       RANK() OVER (order by SUM(case when PolicyTypeID = 4 then ColPrem*ModeValue * 0.07
                                      else  ColPrem*ModeValue + ExcessPrem * 0.07
                                 end) as RANK2,

       SUM(case when PolicyTypeID = 4 then ColPrem*ModeValue * 0.07
                else  ColPrem*ModeValue + ExcessPrem * 0.07
           end)
from tblAppsInfo
where CompanyID in (select CompanyID from tblCompanyInfo where DeptID = 7)
group by AgtID
order by Rank;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use a case statement inside the sum.

```
CASE WHEN PolicyTypeID = 4 THEN SUM(ColPrem*ModeValue) * 0.07 
ELSE SUM((ColPrem*ModeValue) + (ExcessPrem * 0.07)) END
```

Comment: I chose another as the answer as it was more complete, but this is also correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing everything together you can divide and conquer: create a base statement in a `CTE` and use it in the main query

```
WITH PT AS (
  SELECT AgtID
       , RankType = 8
       , RankValue4 = SUM(CASE WHEN PolicyTypeID = 4 
                               THEN ColPrem*ModeValue 
                               ELSE 0 
                          END) * 0.07
       , RankValue = SUM(CASE WHEN PolicyTypeID = 4 
                              THEN 0 
                              ELSE (ColPrem*ModeValue) + (ExcessPrem * 0.07) 
                         END)
  FROM   tblAppsInfo
  WHERE  CompanyID in (SELECT CompanyID 
                       FROM   tblCompanyInfo
                       WHERE  DeptID = 7)
  GROUP BY AgtID
)
INSERT INTO tblAgentRank (AgtID, RankType, Rank, TimeFrame, RankValue)
SELECT AgtID, RankType
     , RANK() OVER (ORDER BY RankValue4 + RankValue DESC) as Rank
     , 'Y', RankValue4 + RankValue
FROM   PT
```

It's a little unclear to me if the first part of the formula:

> If PolicyTypeID = 4, calculate SUM(ColPrem*ModeValue) * 0.07

it's really `SUM(ColPrem*ModeValue) * 0.07` or it's `SUM((ColPrem*ModeValue) * 0.07)`, I implemented the former, to change the implementation to the second form just move the multiplication inside the `CASE`.

Comment: This also works. And the 7% could be calculated either way in this instance, I think. Thanks for the input!